# Difference between expressEngine and ng2engine

Tags: express, typescript, angular, angular2-universal

I am using [universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter).

For the file **server.ts**, when I change

```
import { expressEngine } from 'angular2-universal';
app.engine('.html', expressEngine);
```

to

```
import { ng2engine } from 'angular2-universal';
app.engine('.html', ng2engine);
```

seems no influence on the demo.

So what is the difference between `expressEngine` and `ng2engine`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I found the explanation:
https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/ecd1ebc3dbf368fcaf9ff1804636363cba9e4723/modules/express-engine/src/engine.ts#L133

> DEPRECATION WARNING: `ng2engine` is no longer supported and will be
>   removed in next release. use `expressEngine`'

So right now should use `expressEngine`